# Values ​of combobox with space in the text

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have a combobox that feeds from a mysql request. The problem if the result has space seems wrong

If i have in mysql:
test1 in my combobox i have test1 = OK
test 2 in my combobox i have {test 2} = Wrong

```
#FRAME INFO
frame_info = LabelFrame (Product, text = 'Info Maker',height=240,width=1000)
frame_info.place (x=220, y=10)

combo_maker = ttk.Combobox(frame_info,state="readonly")
#combo_maker['value'] = combo_input()
combo_maker['value'] = combo_input()
combo_maker.current(0)
combo_maker.place(x=5, y=5, height = 25, width = 180)

#FRAME INFO
```

Comment: Please show the result of `combo_input()`. If you pass a proper list or tuple, it should function correctly.

Comment: Show the image. https://imgur.com/nvM4wFk. Is with mysql test.

Comment: No i mean the return result from your function `combo_input`, not after you pass it to the combobox. Simple `print (combo_input())` and show what it is.

Comment: I have ```[('test 1',), ('test 2',), ('test3',)]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result from mysql is a list of tuples. You will need to flatten them first before inserting into a combobox.

The below showcases the difference before and after flattening:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def combo_input():
    return [('test 1',), ('test 2',), ('test3',)]

a_combo_maker = ttk.Combobox(root,state="readonly")
a_combo_maker["value"] = combo_input()
a_combo_maker.current(0)
a_combo_maker.pack()

b_combo_maker = ttk.Combobox(root,state="readonly")
b_combo_maker["value"] = [item for result in combo_input() for item in result if item]
b_combo_maker.current(0)
b_combo_maker.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works. What happens when looking at the tutorials I have read. There is nothing reference to that. And I did not know. 
I will use that daily. Thank you