# How to remove {} from ttk.Combobox listbox?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Stack Exchange, so please bear with me in case I have entered this question wrong.

I am creating an application using Python 3.7 and tkinter and sqlite3 that will have a window with multiple frames that can be navigated through.  I have entry fields where someone enters data, and sqlite3 stores it in a table.  Then that data is added into a combo-box.  When the database entry is a string with multiple words, the combo-box shows it with {} around the item.

My question is: How can I add items to a combo-box list-box without the {}?

Below is a minimum example.  If you enter a multi-word string on Frame 1 (e.g. "John Smith"), the combo-box on Frame 2 will show {John Smith}.

```
# Imports
import sqlite3 as sql
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# Database setup
conn = sql.connect(r"C:\Users\cecke\Desktop\Table.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_table([index] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [name] text)""")
conn.commit()


# Window
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame = Frame1(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.geometry("300x300")

    def navigate(self, frame):
        self.frame.pack_forget()
        self.frame = frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()


# Frame 1
class Frame1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.frame1_title = tk.Label(self, text="Frame 1").pack()
        self.frame1_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.frame1_entry.pack()
        self.frame1_button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", command=self.db_enter).pack()
        self.frame1_button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Next Frame", command=self.frame2_show).pack()

    def db_enter(self):
        new_data = self.frame1_entry.get()
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO db_table (name) VALUES (?)""", (new_data,))
        conn.commit()
        self.frame1_entry.delete(0, "end")

    def frame2_show(self):
        self.master.navigate(Frame2)


# Frame 2
class Frame2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        cur.execute('''SELECT name FROM db_table''')
        frame2_combo_data = cur.fetchall()
        self.frame2_title = tk.Label(self, text="Frame 2").pack()
        self.frame2_combo = ttk.Combobox(self, value=frame2_combo_data).pack()
        self.frame2_button = tk.Button(self, text="Back", command=self.frame1_show).pack()

    def frame1_show(self):
        self.master.navigate(Frame1)


# Run
Start = Window()
Start.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you show the result of `print (frame2_combo_data)`? Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947957/values-of-combobox-with-space-in-the-text/55948410#55948410) can help.

Comment: It would help if your example didn't include a file path that is only valid on your machine.

Comment: My apologies on the file path.  But the link you shared Henry worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a list of lists to a tkinter function that requires a list of strings. Tkinter is a thin wrapper around a tcl/tk interpreter. When a tkinter function is given value that it expects to be a string but is instead a list, the internal tcl/tk interpreter will convert it to a string using its own list-to-string algorithm. That algorithm adds curly braces in order to preserve the internal list-like structure.

The simplest solution is for your code to take the responsibility of converting the list of lists to a list of strings before passing the values to the combobox.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I ended up converting the list of lists to a list of strings.  I'm glad you actually explained the terminology, it helps with attempting to understand whats going on.